# Matching a set of objects within an array based on a different array of search property values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Is there a nicer way to filter an object array based on a set of possible values for a particular property?

This works but seems a bit clunky.

```
const all = [
  {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3} ...
]
const ids = [2, 3];

const selected = (all, ids) =>
  all.filter(obj => ids.map(id => id === obj.id).some(match => match));

selected(all, ids);
// [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

In Python it'd be something like this:

```
selected = [obj for obj in all if obj.id in ids]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter out the array using `Array.filter()` and `Array.includes()`:

```js
const all = [ {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3} ];
const ids = [2, 3];

const selected = (all, ids) => all.filter(obj => ids.includes(obj.id));
  
console.log(selected(all,ids));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use of `Array.filter`, `object destructuration` and `Array.includes`, like :

```js
const all = [{
  id: 1,
}, {
  id: 2,
}, {
  id: 3,
}];

const ids = [
  2,
  3,
];

const selected = (all, ids) => all.filter(({
  id,
}) => ids.includes(id));

console.log(selected(all, ids));
// [{id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

Comment: Nice answer! I got to say, though, multiline destructuring looks ugly.

Comment: Ditto -  a correct answer, but not sure the destructuring is required and the second answer without it is easier to read.

Comment: @GuyBowden It's more of a personnal opinion in this one. There is no *good* answer to use destructuring or not in here. I personnaly prefer it so you know exactly what is used in the function; at the start of it. Avoid the use of the dot notation. I respect your choice of not using it in here tho :)

Comment: @GuyBowden It's readable alright. Remove newlines: `all.filter(({id}) => ids.includes(id))`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It's a part of the norm I'm applying to my code (always open json and put a comma after each key). Ofc you can put it in one line :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the wanted `id` and check against for filtering.

```js
const
    all = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    ids = [2, 3],
    result = all.filter((s => ({ id }) => s.has(id))(new Set(ids)));

console.log(result);
```